# Enable or disable filters in WHERE clause depending on variable values and CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very long query, but the important part is the `WHERE`. What I want is to be able to enable or disable "chunks" of it depending on variables declared previously, so I avoid composing it using concatenation.

This is my attempt:

```
DECLARE @previousReadingEqualsZero AS            BIT = 0
DECLARE @previousReadingBiggerThanLastReading AS BIT = 0
DECLARE @readingIncidentIds AS                   TABLE
                                                 (
                                                     Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                                                 )

-- Tons of CTEs and JOINS...

WHERE (CASE
           WHEN @previousReadingEqualsZero = 1 THEN CTE_PreviousReadings.Consumption = 0
           ELSE TRUE END)
  AND (CASE
           WHEN @previousReadingBiggerThanLastReading = 1
               THEN CTE_PreviousReadings.Consumption > CTE_MostRecentReadings.Consumption
           ELSE TRUE END)
  AND (CASE
           WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM @readingIncidentIds) = TRUE
               THEN CTE_MostRecentReadingIncidents.Id IN (@readingIncidentIds)
           ELSE TRUE END)
```

But SQL Server doesn't like it:

[image]

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 187 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg
> 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 194 Incorrect syntax near '='.

What's wrong with my approach? Is there any way to achieve what I want without having to concatenate strings to compose the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** not a statement; it returns a scalar value not a boolean result. Use `AND` and `OR` logic: `((@previousReadingEqualsZero = 1 AND CTE_PreviousReadings.Consumption) OR @previousReadingEqualsZero =0)`. You'll then also likely then want to add a `RECOMPILE` to your option clause to avoid bad query plan caching.

Comment: Also `EXISTS` *is* a boolean operator; you don't do `EXISTS(<sub query>) = TRUE`; `EXISTS` returns a true or false result already so you don't compare it to anything.

Comment: At least when using SQL Server... (However, the above syntax is ANSI SQL compliant. ) Anyway, it's generally better to use regular AND/OR constructions in the WHERE clause instead of case expressions.

Comment: @ThomA Thanks a lot for your comment. Yes, I thought about that approach too, but I was trying to take advantage of the short-circuit evaluation of the `CASE` statement.

Comment: The `CASE` (in the `WHERE` on the columns) would make the query non-SARGable, @amedina , so it would be detrimental to the performance, not beneficial.

Comment: For these queries, it can actually make sense to "compose it by concatenation" as you call it, you might even get better performance

Comment: @ThomA Ok, I will use boolean expressions instead. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `CASE` here, just use normal boolean logic. `CASE` is an expression which returns a value such as `0` or `1`, it does not return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

```sql
WHERE (@previousReadingEqualsZero = 0 OR CTE_PreviousReadings.Consumption = 0)
  AND (@previousReadingBiggerThanLastReading = 0 OR CTE_PreviousReadings.Consumption > CTE_MostRecentReadings.Consumption)
  AND (CTE_MostRecentReadingIncidents.Id IN (@readingIncidentIds)
       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @readingIncidentIds)
      )
```

The code `CTE_MostRecentReadingIncidents.Id IN (@readingIncidentIds)` looks wrong though, because it appears it's a table variable. If so you need this:

```sql
  AND (CTE_MostRecentReadingIncidents.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @readingIncidentIds)
       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @readingIncidentIds)
      )
```

I would advise you to store the result of the `NOT EXISTS` in a variable before the query and use that instead, so as to elide that semi-join.

```sql
  AND (@haveReadingIncidentIds = 0 OR
       CTE_MostRecentReadingIncidents.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @readingIncidentIds)
      )
```